# Is there a php code that get user email automatically?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to send a html file, the receiver email is goo@eg.com, is there a way to get his email automatically and auto fill it in the email field of my html file?

Am sending using Turbo mailer

Here is a little part of the **code**

input type="hidden" id="AP___" name="login" value="autofill here"

Comment: Where do you want to retrieve it from? If your users login, then you could get it from your user database and populate it when you draw the form. I doubt there's a way your PHP code could retrieve it from the client machine, that sounds like a terrible security breach. Lots of browsers will auto-fill the forms with locally-held data, but you won't see that until it is submitted.

Comment: I am trying to personalize the html file for each recipients emails, i need a code that gets the email from my list and inputs it automatically into the email field

Comment: OK, so does your user log in somehow? If they do, then you have their id and can retrieve it from the database and echo it when you're outputting the form.

Comment: I have their id's, just need to be able to retrieve it

Comment: I am sending it as a file, not through a link

Comment: I'm really not sure what you are asking now. How does your site know which user you want to send the file to? If you are selecting the user from a database of users, then once you have picked the user, retrieve their email using their unique id, then put it into the form code as appropriate.

Comment: It is actually an offline html document, i am trying to personalize the file to each of my recipients